# How do I utilize a timer in Android?

Tags: java, android, timer, intervals

I need to collect data on an interval, here the data collection is simulated with a counting integer.  I can't seem to collect that integer though.  I need the collection to start after a button is clicked and end when another is clicked.  Any ideas?

```
package com.example.test.gothedistance;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button start, stop;
TextView sumText;
int count;
Timer t;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    stop = (Button) findViewById((R.id.stopButton));
    sumText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sumTV);
    t = new Timer();
    count = 0;




    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(
            new TimerTask()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    count++;

                }
            },0,2000);

  stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            t.cancel();
            sumText.setText(count);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: I think that you are looking for something like this: http://android-er.blogspot.com.es/2013/12/example-of-using-timer-and-timertask-on.html hope it helps!

Comment: I would also say that Timer is not normally used in Android, usually its either an alarm or a delayed message to a handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely with the line `sumText.setText(count)`, which uses [`TextView.setText(int resid)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)). That means it's looking for an id equal to `count`, rather than displaying the value of count. You need to convert this value to an integer first:

```
sumText.setText(Integer.toString(count))
```

Comment: Oh jeez, that's embarrassing (I've been using a language which would have taken care of that problem automatically :b)